# How to install KeyDb?

Tags: package-management

I have Ubuntu 22.4 and want to install KeyDb.

But I receive "Unable to locate package keydb" after (as described in the doc):

$ echo "deb https://download.keydb.dev/open-source-dist $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/keydb.list
$ sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/keydb.gpg https://download.keydb.dev/open-source-dist/keyring.gpg
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install keydb

How to fix it?